# Ruby on Rails: calculate time difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, helper

I'm trying to calculate the "time left" for my records in Rails 5. My records have a `created_at` column (UTC).

Each record lasts 24 hours, I have a global scope on my model:

```
scope :available, -> { where(
  created_at: (Time.current - 24.hours)..Time.current
) }
```

Now, on the front-end side, here is what I need:

```
Record id 1: 23:59:12
Record id 2: 22:23:03
...
```

After some researches, I've found some helper doing the work but it looks SO ugly, that's why I'm asking for your help.

Here is my (sucky but working) code:

```
# In my helper:
def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
  seconds_diff = (start_time - end_time).to_i.abs

  hours = seconds_diff / 3600
  seconds_diff -= hours * 3600

  minutes = seconds_diff / 60
  seconds_diff -= minutes * 60

  seconds = seconds_diff

  "#{hours.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{minutes.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}:#{seconds.to_s.rjust(2, '0')}"
end

# And my the view:
time_diff(Time.current - 24.hours, model_instance.created_at)
```

I'm sure I'm missing some awesome Rails helper which could make all this one-liner :)

Thanks for reading me.

Comment: an approximation would be [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words). For your specific requirement there is no native way in rails.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the Time Difference Gem

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/tmlee/time_difference

```
start_time = Time.new(2013,1)
end_time = Time.new(2014,1)
TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_each_component
=> {:years=>1.0, :months=>12.0, :weeks=>52.14, :days=>365.0, :hours=>8760.0, :minutes=>525600.0, :seconds=>31536000.0}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure that bringing a Gem for a simple task like this is really better than an helper method :-/

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [Time](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Time.html) class from Ruby Core Library. Using `Time.at(seconds)` to create a new Time object with the given number of seconds since the Epoch. Since your time window is less than 24 hours, you can call `strftime` directly without doing any further calculations.

```
def time_diff(start_time, end_time)
 seconds_diff = (start_time - end_time).abs
 Time.at(seconds_diff).utc.strftime "%H:%M:%S"
end
```

You should avoid calling to `to_i` as it would reduce the accuracy of the time left